# Функция zip() объединяет 2 массива не полностью

Tags: python, массивы, словари, bs4, кортежи

Есть список с цифрами(values):

```
list_b = ['2021-09-14', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '212', '212', '5.0', '100.0%', 
'2021-09-13', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '159', '159', '5.0', '100.0%',
'2021-09-11', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '145', '145', '5.0', '100.0%', 
'2021-09-10', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '196', '196', '5.0', '100.0%', 
'2021-09-09', '0', '0', '0', '6', '0', '111', '117', '4.9', '94.87%', 
'2021-09-08', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '103', '103', '5.0', '100.0%', 
'2021-09-07', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '201', '201', '5.0', '100.0%',
'2021-09-06', '3', '0', '0', '0', '0', '135', '135', '5.0', '100.0%', 
'2021-09-04', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '95', '95', '5.0', '100.0%', 
'2021-09-03', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '127', '127', '5.0', '100.0%']
```

И список с названиями(keys):

```
list_a = ["Дата: ", "с ошибкой: ", "с оценкой 1: ", "с оценкой 2: ", "с оценкой 3: ", 
"с оценкой 4: ", "с оценкой 5: ", "Всего: ", "Среднее: ", "Процент удовлетворенности: "]
```

Хочу это оформить в виде словаря и потом записать в .csv файл в таком виде:
[image: Таблица .csv]

Запускаю код:

```
for keys, values in zip(list_a, list_b):
    print(keys, values)
```

Но результат выполнения программы - только первый элемент из списка b:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слишком много лишних движений, кроме того, вы поленились почитать документацию про функцию zip. Воспользуйтесь модулем pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

list_b = ['2021-09-14', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '212', '212', '5.0', '100.0%', 
'2021-09-13', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '159', '159', '5.0', '100.0%',
'2021-09-11', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '145', '145', '5.0', '100.0%', 
'2021-09-10', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '196', '196', '5.0', '100.0%', 
'2021-09-09', '0', '0', '0', '6', '0', '111', '117', '4.9', '94.87%', 
'2021-09-08', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '103', '103', '5.0', '100.0%', 
'2021-09-07', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '201', '201', '5.0', '100.0%',
'2021-09-06', '3', '0', '0', '0', '0', '135', '135', '5.0', '100.0%', 
'2021-09-04', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '95', '95', '5.0', '100.0%', 
'2021-09-03', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '127', '127', '5.0', '100.0%']

list_a = ["Дата: ", "с ошибкой: ", "с оценкой 1: ", "с оценкой 2: ", "с оценкой 3: ", 
"с оценкой 4: ", "с оценкой 5: ", "Всего: ", "Среднее: ", "Процент удовлетворенности: "]

data = [list_b[x:x+10] for x in range(0, len(list_b), 10)]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=list_a)
```

теперь df у вас:

```
       Дата:  с ошибкой:   ... Среднее:  Процент удовлетворенности: 
0  2021-09-14           0  ...       5.0                      100.0%
1  2021-09-13           0  ...       5.0                      100.0%
2  2021-09-11           0  ...       5.0                      100.0%
3  2021-09-10           0  ...       5.0                      100.0%
4  2021-09-09           0  ...       4.9                      94.87%
5  2021-09-08           0  ...       5.0                      100.0%
6  2021-09-07           0  ...       5.0                      100.0%
7  2021-09-06           3  ...       5.0                      100.0%
8  2021-09-04           0  ...       5.0                      100.0%
9  2021-09-03           0  ...       5.0                      100.0%
```

Ну а далее датафрейм можно сразу записать в csv:

```
df.to_csv('filename.csv')
```

Comment: https://pythonru.com/uroki/funkcija-zip-dlja-nachinajushhih
Я читал тут, но не утверждаю, что информация здесь исчерпывающая.
Возможно ли решить задачу не прибегая к pandas?

Answer (score 2):

Разобрать в словарь можно так, хотя я и не уверен, какой именно вы хотите словарь:

```
d = {key: list_b[i::len(list_a)] for i, key in enumerate(list_a)}
print(d)
```

Вывод:

```
{
'Дата: ': ['2021-09-14', '2021-09-13', '2021-09-11', '2021-09-10', '2021-09-09', '2021-09-08', '2021-09-07', '2021-09-06', '2021-09-04', '2021-09-03'], 
'с ошибкой: ': ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '3', '0', '0'], 
'с оценкой 1: ': ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 
'с оценкой 2: ': ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 
'с оценкой 3: ': ['0', '0', '0', '0', '6', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 
'с оценкой 4: ': ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 
'с оценкой 5: ': ['212', '159', '145', '196', '111', '103', '201', '135', '95', '127'], 
'Всего: ': ['212', '159', '145', '196', '117', '103', '201', '135', '95', '127'], 
'Среднее: ': ['5.0', '5.0', '5.0', '5.0', '4.9', '5.0', '5.0', '5.0', '5.0', '5.0'], 
'Процент удовлетворенности: ': ['100.0%', '100.0%', '100.0%', '100.0%', '94.87%', '100.0%', '100.0%', '100.0%', '100.0%', '100.0%']
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Подскажите, за что лучше почитать, чтобы понять как строятся такие конструкции?
Я правильно понял, что это генераторы?

Comment: @ЗахарЕлисеев Это не совсем генератор. В данном случае это *словарное включение* (dict comprehension), плюс *срез* (slice) с шагом, плюс встроенная функция `enumerate`. Всё это легко гуглится.